# Computing cost for Givens rotation to yield QR

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I would like to derive the operation cost for the Givens QR factorization of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $m > n$.

There are $m-n$ columns to add to make a square matrix. In this square $m=n$ matrix, there are $(m-1) + \cdots + (m-n)+ \cdots +3 + 2 + 1 = \frac{m(m-1)}{2}$ lower off-diagonal elements. This can be written as $$\frac{(m-1)m}{2} - \frac{(n-1)n}{2}$$~~

Each Givens rotation is a matrix and vector product which has $m$ multiplications and $m-1$ additions: $2m - 1$ total.

So I though the total operations would be: $$(\frac{(m-1)m}{2} - \frac{(n-1)n}{2}) \cdot (2m-1)$$
but this is not correct. Where is my counting error?

According to Higham's *Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms* the operational cost is: $$3n^2( m - \frac{n}{3})$$

Any hints?

---

Consider $G_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ which takes $a_{ij} \to 0$. $G_{ij} \mathbf{a}_{j}$ uses $m$ dot-products. Per dot-product, there are $m$ multiplications and $m-1$ additions: $m + (m-1) = 2m-1$. Therefore, there are $m(2m-1) = \boxed{ 2m^2 - m }$ total flops per Givens rotation.

I claim there are $$\boxed{\frac{(m-1)m}{2} - \frac{(m-n-1)(m-n)}{2}}$$ total Givens rotations.

Therefore, there (should) be $$\left ( \frac{(m-1)m}{2} - \frac{(m-n-1)(m-n)}{2}\right ) \left ( 2m^2 - m \right)$$
total FLOPS.

However, this is not what is claimed by my reference.

---

Final attempt:
Consider the first column of $A$. There are $m-1$ entries which must be eliminated. Each entry requires a Givens rotation which has $4$ multiplications and $2$ additions applied to $n$ columns. This yields $\boxed{6n\cdot (M-1)}$ flops.

Consider the second column of $A$. There are $m-2$ entries and as before, there are $4$ multiplications and $2$ additions, but this time applied to $n-1$ columns. This yields: $\boxed{6(n-1)(m-2)}$

We continue until the $n$th column. There are $m - n$ entries and $1$ column. this yields: $\boxed{6\cdot 1 \cdot (m -n)}$

Summing the above we obtain the total flops:

$$\boxed{6\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left ( n-k\right )\left ( m - k - 1\right )}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first column you reduce $m-1$ elements to zero using row operations on $n-1$ non-trivial row elements. Then in the next column you have to reduce $m-2$ elements to zero using row operations on $n-2$ non-trivial row elements. Etc. Each operation on row elements is a multiplication of a 2D rotation matrix with a 2D vector. Taking this as elementary operation gives a total cost
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n(m-k)(n-k)=mn^2-(m+n)\frac{n(n+1)}2+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6
\\
=\frac{mn(n-1)}2-\frac{n(n+1)(n-1)}{6}=\frac{n(n-1)}2(m-\frac{n+1}3)
$$
This is about the claimed complexity, if multiplied by the operations count for a 2D rotation, in a straightforward implementation amounting to 4 multiplication and 2 additions. There is also additional cost of normalizing the rotation matrices, but that has a lower degree $\sim mn$.

Comment: I am not understanding how you are counting. In your first sentence, you discuss row operations on $n-1$ non-trivial row elements. Do you refer to the row elements of $A$? But $n$ denotes the number of columns. 

We reduce the $m-1$ elements in the first column by applying $m-1$ Givens rotations.

Comment: The $m×n$ matrix $A$ has $m$ rows and $n$ columns. Each column has a total of $m$ elements, each row has $n$ elements. In the QR method you apply Givens rotations from the left, which amounts to operations with entire rows. The aim is to eliminate the sub-diagonal elements against the diagonal elements. The leading terms are known, so the row operations act on reduced rows, if the order of left-to-right is observed.

Comment: I think we are saying the same thing except you are discussing rows instead of columns. Could you please take a look at my edit for my latest attempt? I will learn best if I can understand what is wrong with my counting method.

Comment: I do not understand what you are doing there. It appears that you apply a matrix multiplication of the full matrices for the Givens rotation? $G_{ij}$ is the identity matrix with 4 elements at the corners of a square changed. This means that in the product, all but 2 rows remain unchanged. Mask out the unchanged rows and what remains is a $(2\times 2)·(2\times n)$ multiplication. Now observe that a sub-diagonal zero pattern is systematically produced to filter out even more trivial operations.

Comment: Thank you for your information Lutz. I now see the errors in my counting process. I have updated my post to include my answer which is similar to what you wrote.

Comment: Yes, with a slight correction. In the leading column you know that the lower entry becomes zero, so it need not be computed. The original leading entries are factored as $rc$ and $rs$ with $c^2+s^2=1$, after rotation they are $r$ and $0$. But then the computation of $r$ via square root of a sum of squares and $c,s$ via division adds to the operation count. So what your approach produces is closer to the truth, while the same terms are the same.